# Feedback form placement

Tags: feedback

**Intro**:
I am working on a software which is a video consultation platform between brokers and his customers. **The problem is where to include the feedback form.**

A broker is in a consultation with a client. Problems arise with this. You try to fix the problems a few times by turning the audio and screen sharing on and off. Reloads don't help either.

Neither the screen sharing nor the audio work properly and so the broker decides to call the customer. Since screen sharing does not work during the phone call either, the broker switches to an alternative application. So he is not wasting too much time in the stress and offering the customer the best possible service. Therefore, during the call with the customer, he exits the software as soon as possible in order to start the alternative application.

The broker does not have the time or the desire to fill out the feedback form at the moment.

Comment: Have you thought about collecting the usage log and do log analysis on the application? Log analysis can reveal usage patterns and identify pain points where the users exit the application out of frustration.

Comment: Hi, Thanks :), I didnt know log analysis could be used to know user behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is you should really check whether it is the actual problem that you think it is:

1. As @Eric said you can request for usage log from the backend end development team, which will give you an idea how many times the user had issues with the conference.

Other way to find out the problem is:
2. Creating a weekly or a recurring task to the broker to take feedback as in that stress moment(when he tries to use inbuilt conferencing and fails) the Broker may not be able to contribute any feedback as he will be in rush to catch his lead.